# Problems with sendBroadcast(String Action) in PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

Long time lurker - first time poster! I hope someone can help with my little problem;

I've got a *PreferenceFragment* which implements an *OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* which then should fire a sendBroadcast() to my *AlarmReceiver* in order to set up a repeating alarm service.
I can see that the listener registers the onChange event and goes all the way down to the *getActivity().sendBroadcast()* - but unfortunately the broadcast is never caught by my AlarmReceiver.

Here's my PreferencesFragment;

```
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Preference preference = findPreference(key);
    if (preference instanceof CheckBoxPreference) {
        //Intent alarmReceiverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        Intent alarmReceiverIntent = new Intent(getString(R.string.ACTION_SET_NOTIFICATIONS));
        //alarmReceiverIntent.setAction(getActivity().getString(R.string.ACTION_SET_NOTIFICATIONS));
        getActivity().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(alarmReceiverIntent);
    }
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {        
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   //This is just to see if the AlarmReceiver has caught the broadcast.
   Log.v(TAG, "We are in the receiver - yay");
```

Lastly the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="dk.aau.student.b211.sleepattention.SET_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I hope that there's someone out there that can help :)

Comment: Check your `ACTION_SET_NOTIFICATIONS`

Answer (score 0):

Okay - so I found a solution!
If you have problems receiving your broadcasts then you have to register the BroadCastReceiver as a receiver. This solved my problem :) Remember to unregister in onPause and register in onResume.

E.g.;

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, new IntentFilter(getString(R.string.ACTION_SET_NOTIFICATIONS)));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(alarmReceiver);
}
```